# React Native Expo Audio API - Sync UI Elements

Tags: react-native, animation, audio, expo, closed-captions

Is there any way to sync UI elements or animations to sound playing in the Expo Audio SDK?
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/audio/

I couldn't find much more on this topic in the official docs and googling turned up pretty dry.

Effectively, I was looking for something like:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avsynchronizedlayer